# How to convert a loop that sometimes adds a transformed value to a Java 8 stream/lambda?

Tags: java, lambda, java-8, java-stream

How do you convert this into a Java 8 lambda expression?

```
List<String> inputStrings = new ArrayList<>(); // say, a list of inputStrings

ArrayList<SomeClass> outputResultStrings = new ArrayList();
for(String anInputString : inputStrings) {
    SomeClass someResult = doSomthing(anInputString);
    if (someResult != null) {
        outputResultStrings.add(someResult);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you need a `ArrayList<SomeClass` or will a `List<SomeClass>` do?

Answer (score 7):

Your code essentially loops over the input strings, performs `doSomthing` on each of them ([`map`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#map-java.util.function.Function-) in Java's terminology), ignores the results that are `null` ([`filter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#filter-java.util.function.Predicate-) in Java's terminology) and then produces a list of those results ([`collect`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#collect-java.util.stream.Collector-) in Java's terminology). And when you put it all together:

```
List<SomeClass> outputResultStrings = 
    inputStrings.stream()
                .map(SomeClass::doSomething)
                .filter(x -> x != null)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

EDIT:
As suggested by Tunaki, the not-null check can be cleaned up with [`Objects::nonNull`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Objects.html#nonNull-java.lang.Object-):

```
List<SomeClass> outputResultStrings = 
    inputStrings.stream()
                .map(SomeClass::doSomething)
                .filter(Objects::nonNull)
                .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    List<String> inputStrings = new ArrayList<>(); // say, a list of inputStrings

    List<SomeClass> outputResultStrings = inputStrings.stream()
        .map(s -> doSomthing(s))
        .filter(e -> e != null)
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ArrayList<SomeClass> list = inputStrings.stream()
    .map(SomeClass::doSomthing)
    .filter((someClazz)->{ 
              return someClazz!=null;
    })
    .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Comment: I know about the function. If you read the doc it says:"There are no guarantees on the type, mutability, serializability, or thread-safety of the List returned" and in the example it seems he wants it in a ArrayList.

Comment: You have to choose an implementation when creating a list.

Comment: @ThorbjørnRavnAndersen I don't understand what you mean by that. Could you explain or write a small example? I am new to Java 8 so quite possibly I am missing something.

Comment: `(someClazz)->{ return someClazz!=null; }` is a verbose way of saying `someClazz -> someClazz!=null`.